# About the complexity of a path finding attack for a path encrypted with a block cipher (like AES). How many AES calculations count as secure?

Tags: encryption, aes, cryptanalysis, attack, security-definition

Out of $N = s^3$ total points we pick a starting point $p$ and an end point $q$
with
$$p=(p_1, p_2)$$
$$q=(q_1,q_2)$$
$$p_1,q_1 \in [0,s)$$
$$p_2,q_2 \in [0,s^2)$$
We want to find a path in between them.

For doing so we have two kinds of progression:

- A trivial one by just walking forward:
  $$f((e_1,e_2)) = ((e_1+1 \bmod s),e_2)$$
- And an advanced one by jumping from one point $(e_1,e_2)$ to another $(e'_1,e'_2)$.
  This connection is encrypted ( $E$ ) with a symmetric, format preserving block cipher (similar to AES but with bigger block size) with domain $[0,t-1]$ with $t = s^{3+a}$ with $0>a<1$ (*) ($t$ is related to the block size in most cases. For AES $t$ would be $2^{128}$)
  They are connected if:
  $$E(e_1+e_2\cdot s) + E(e'_1+e'_2\cdot s) = t-1$$
  Given a random point $(r_1,r_2)$ we can use the decryption ( $D$ ) to find it's connection with:
  $$D(t-1-E(r_1+r_2\cdot s)) = v \in [0,t-1]$$
  Iff $v<s^3$ it's a valid connection and we can decode it to the related point $(r'_1,r'_2)$
  This has a property of $\frac{\textstyle s^3}{\textstyle s^{3+a}} = s^{-a}$. So in mean it will take $s^a$ forward steps to find a valid connection. As we can only take $s-1$ steps forward $a$ has a more limited upper bound than in (*) to avoid dead ends. $a \approx 0.8$ seems to be good choice for target $s$-size.

---

To find a connection in between points $p$ and $q$ we 'just' need to start exploring from both sides and jump to points $ {p^i}',{q^j}'$ with equal second value ${p_2^i}' ={q_2^j}'$. Similar to Giant-Step this should take in mean $\approx \sqrt{s^2} = s$ jumps. (Update edit) According to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4468655/710455)  a more accurate value is $\sqrt{\pi}\cdot s$ total jumps.

Combined with the mean number of trials to find a valid jump location ( $s^a$ ) an adversary would need to calculate in mean $\approx  s^a\cdot \sqrt{\pi} \cdot s = \sqrt{\pi} \cdot s^{1+a}$ block cipher (encryption and decryption). This is much smaller than the normal effort for breaking a $t=s^{3+a}$-Bit Block-Cipher.

(we assume a suitable $a$ has been chosen without any dead ends and the adversary has access to all run time variables including the block cipher keys)

**Q1** Is this approximation for the number of block cipher calculations correct? Can it done faster? 
**Q2** As single bit have big impact for block cipher security is there a more accurate calculation for the mean count of block cipher encryption required to find a connection in between $p$ and $q$?
**Q3** On https://www.keylength.com/en/1/ there is some overview about the security of different values. Would this kind of encryption described here similar to a $\log_2(\sqrt{\pi}s^{1+a})$-bit keylength symmetric block cipher encryption? If not what else?

The **main Q**uestion would be if a 192-bit block size is good enough for this. According to the approximation above (and $a=0.8$) it would take in mean $\approx 2^{92}$ block cipher calculations to break it. If this is equal to a 92-symmetric block cipher this would not be considered as secure anymore in near future $\approx$ year $2030$ (according to the link above). $\rightarrow $**Update**: AES-192 won't work out. It only supports a block size of 128 bits. Changed it to a block cipher similar to AES but with a block size of 192. E.g. Rijndael (or is there any more common?)

($a$ can be tweaked but this will not gain much more than a factor of $\approx 16$ else chance for dead ends gets too high)

---

**Main Q2**: Can we introduce multiple (3) different Block Cipher without big impact on security?
(could als be part of a new thread)

Instead of a single advanced way of progression we can now jump from one point to up to two different points.
Given a point $(e_1,e_2)$ the kind of progression depends if $e_2 \bmod 3$ is $0,1$ or $2$.

$$[i]_3 \rightarrow [j]_3: D_j(t-1 - E_i(e_1+e_2\cdot s)) \text{ with } i,j\in{0,1,2}$$
$E_k,D_k$ means we encrypt, decrypt with the $k$-th Block-Cipher. To use $E_i$ the value $e_2$ need to hold $e_2 \bmod 3= i$. After using decryption $D_j$ the resulting value not only need to be $<s^3$ the resulting point $(e_1','e_2')$ also need to hold $e_2' \bmod 3 = j$.
This reduces the chances for a single connection but also increases chances for any connection.
**MQ2** Does this have any significant impact on security?

---

This path encryption is related to a slightly modified/simplified version of an answer in [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/100452/65149). I would like to be more certain about the security of this.

Comment: Is the space $[0,s^3-1)$? or something else which can be reasonably encoded? Is BC short for block cipher?

Comment: Changed BC to block cipher. The space should be $[0,s^3-1]$ or written different $[0,s^3)$ or? $s$ is related to the block cipher domain $t = s^{3+a}$. If we chose a $K$-bit block cipher (with $K$-bit block size) the cycle size $s$ would be of size $2^{\frac{K}{3+a}}$ (rounded to the next whole number and change $a$ to fit that number). A point $(e_1,e_2)$ can be encoded to a number $n \in [0,s^3-1]$ with $n = e_1 + e_2 \cdot s$ and back again with $e_1 = n \bmod s$ and $e_2 = \lfloor{\frac{n}{s^2}}\rfloor$. (Not 100% if that fits your question).